We have 2 water heaters for different areas. Can I remove the old one and run lines to new water heater for the whole house?
Our home has 2 water heaters that provide hot water to 2 separate parts of our home.  One is old and we would like to disconnect it and run a water line from the new water heater to serve our whole house.  Is this possible.  There are only 2 people in our home.

Do you know why there are currently 2 heaters?  When there are multiple water heaters, the typical reasons are either for capacity of hot water at any one time (lots of showers, large jaccuzzi, etc.), or it's a long run from one heater to get to the whole house, and it took a long time for water to get to the far fixtures, which is both a time and water waster to wait a long time just to get hot water.  Sure it's possible, but depending on how your house is plumbed, there may be a significant length of pipe needed to get hot water from one location to the other to provide hot water everywhere.

if they are next to each other then no problem doing it

If the heaters are in different locations, you may end up waiting longer at some fixtures for hot water if you consolidate to a single location.  If the heaters are basically next to each other, it shouldn't be a problem, as long as you have the same volume (i.e. going from two 40-gal to one 80-gal).

Yes, it's possible. You may have a long wait for hot water, where you are far from the heater, but that's either an acceptable tradeoff or a problem that can be solved in other ways.
If it's a long run between heaters, insulating the pipe will help somewhat, but even in an insulated pipe the hot water will cool down after sitting for a long time, and then all the cooled water will need to be run through the pipe before you get hot water.

With a long run it also helps to keep the pipe as SMALL as possible. People tend to think "big pipe for more free flow" but the problem with hot water is the inventory/volume of water that sits in the pipe and then cools off. Your wait time is proportional to that volume, which is pipe diameter squared.
